# Data Updates and Inserts Inside a lock Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working in an APS.NET MVC application that is sending inserts and updates to SQL Server via Entity Framwork.

My question is if it is wise to put a DataContext statement (read, insert or update) inside a "lock (_object)" block.

For example, like this general pattern:

```
public class EventReporterExample
{
    private readonly object _privateObject = new object();

    public void UpdateValueExample(int value)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_privateObject)
            {
                ReportingDataContext dataContext = new ReportingDataContext(sqlCnxn);

                var exampleData = ( //get the row via LINQ from dataContext ).Single();
                exampleData.Value = value;

                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                dataContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Aren't database connections handled via a pool that manages concurrency issues?

I ask because there seems to be a correlation between more errors in our web site and the fact that I changed the lock statements from "lock (this)" to "lock (_privateObject)", where "this" is, of course, this public class and is used to record events from the web app into the database.

The number of errors per day was usually zero and rarely hit 1-3.  Now after my change, it is usually around 10 but occasionally reaches as high as 90 per day.  We see around 80,000 visitors a day.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest locking on a public object like "this" because that can be locked from outside your class.  That object reference is visible from outside the class so it could leave the potential for someone outside to lock up your thread.  I would absolutely put lock statements on your transactions.  Just how you would interact with any other object that you don't want multiple threads touching at once.

Comment: What type of errors are you getting?  DBConcurrency exceptions that get caught in your sample code's catch block?

Comment: @EMUEVIL re: lock, yes, I changed the lock from a public to a private obj some time ago for the reasons you stated.

Unfortunately, I think the sysadmin made some config changes on the non-sql servers the same day my code change went into effect.  Consequently, I don't know if the existence of these errors and my code changes is coincidental or not.  And the errors I'm seeing aren't db errors, they seem related to the non-sql servers.

I'm not really trying to t-shoot the errs here, just wondering if it is a bad pattern to wrap a db call in a lock or not, particularly in a web app.

Comment: I don't really have the experience to give you best practices in your specific situation.  If you have multiple threads that can read or modify your data objects, then I would control their access with lock statements so you can ensure that you aren't getting any information in a bad state.  Yes, the SQL server should be keeping all the operations atomic, but you still need to control access to your own objects in your code.  All the lock is doing is making sure you don't have two threads interacting with your objects at once.  Can you post the errors you're getting?

Comment: Thanks @EMUEVIL, I appreciate your input.  The errors are error.noresource.402 & I believe Prophecy is throwing those errors.  Proplem is, I see evidence in places that lead me to believe a SQL or Web Service timeout may also be causing those noresource errors in other places too - cascading events.  So, I'm trying to rule out - or rule in - places to focus my attention.  And since I converted the "lock (this)" statements to "lock (_object)", it is notable that these noresource errors started at the same time. However, I also added some dataContext.Dispose() statements in the same places too.

Comment: ... But I wouldn't expect the Dispose() statements to cause problems since they're disposing the dataContexts that were created within the lock-blocks.  So the Dispose() statements seem far less suspicious - just thought I'd throw that out there, though.  That was the only other change that --I-- made that night that is relevant to this conversation.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you here.  there's so many factors that could be causing these errors.  I'm not familar with Prophecy.  I would suggest adding a ton of logging debug statements and then looking through that to see if you can find any patterns.  I've had similar sporadic issues that would only occur a few times a month and this is how I was able to narrow down the surface area that I needed to debug.  Good luck lol.